# Object outside camera OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm using a Perspective View with gluPerspective and gluLookAt and I have the x,y world coordinates of an object. How can I determine if the object is outside the viewable area? Note that the camera is always moving around.

Comment: Frustum Culling is the process of removing everything that is not on the screen so I suggest that the same algorithm can be used to find the opposite result: http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Frustum_Culling.shtml

Comment: But I wanna know if something was removed. I got two cars and the camera is set at the middle point of them. If they get too far away (if they both "leave" the camera) I must put them back in the middle, any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First thing first: OpenGL doesn't have a camera. It just transforms vertices around. And gluLookAt just applies a transformation on the objects that's inverse to a movement of a thought camera.

The solution had already been given in the first comment by Robert Massaioli: In OpenGL a perspective transformation is described in terms of a frustum (*gluPerpective* just calculates frustum parameters and passes these to *glFrustum*). So by determining frustum culling of your objects, i.e. if they are culled, you determine if they're still visible.

Answer (score 0):

When you say they leave the camera do you mean they're off the sides because you're looking  at a fixed distance? ..or do you mean they just vanish.

If it's the first case (off the sides of the shot) you should be able to calculate how far up from the x,y plane you need to move the camera based on your current perspective settings.

If it's the latter case, you probably just need to increase the maximum Z depth to stop them being culled.

**[Edit 1]** In the [gluPerspective](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml) call you set up the viewing angle and the aspect ratio. You should know the distance to your plane and the distance from your center point to the cars so you've got all the information you need. All that's left is a little trigonometry to work out what's viewable and what isn't.

**[Edit 2]** I found [another very useful tutorial](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/view-frustum-culling/) which describes various ways to do the frustum culling you want to do.

Comment: It's the first case. The camera is a fixed distance however it rotates with the cars, that's my main problem.